# having trouble showing SELECT result sql

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, select

i try to get id that gmail = $gmail and use it for UPDATE table

but i can't use from id and showin error Undefined property: mysqli_result::$fetch_assoc

function addverificationcode ($gmail , $random)
{

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DataBaseManager::HOST, DataBaseManager::USER, DataBaseManager::PASSWORD, DataBaseManager::DATABASENAME);
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE gmail='$gmail'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQuery);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $sqlCommand = "UPDATE users
                      SET verificationcode  = '$random' 
                        WHERE id = $result->fetch_assoc()";
    }

    if(mysqli_query($connection, $sqlCommand)){
        return true;
    }else{
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        return false;
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [curly braces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) when calling a method in an object:

```
        $sqlCommand = "UPDATE users
                  SET verificationcode  = '$random' 
                    WHERE id = {$result->fetch_assoc()}";
```

An alternative is using concatenation:

```
        $sqlCommand = "UPDATE users
                  SET verificationcode  = '$random' 
                    WHERE id = " . $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Note that in this case you could combine the two SQL statements into just one, for example `update .. where id = (select id from ...)`.

Also note that your code as posted is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: still say Error description: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: That's because `fetch_assoc` returns an array @BabakRostami.

Comment: can you help me how can i get only one id?? ): @Joni

Answer (score 0):

fetch_assoc gives you the array of the record :)
try this code

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $res['id'];     // you are breaking the array here and storing the array index in a new variable
            $sqlCommand = "UPDATE users
                      SET verificationcode  = '$random' 
                        WHERE id = $id";
       }
    }
```

now it will work. good luck :)